# How to add element on graphql return fields

Tags: ruby, graphql

Im a newbie in Ruby and GraphQL

Currently i have such Mutations module

```
module Mutations
  class ProductCreate < BaseMutation
    # TODO: define return fields
    # field :post, Types::PostType, null: false
    type Types::ProductType

    # TODO: define arguments
    argument :title, String, required: true
    argument :vendor, String, required: false
    argument :store, ID, required: true

    # TODO: define resolve method
    def resolve(title:, vendor:, store:)
      Product.create!(title: title, vendor: vendor, store: store)
    end
  end
end
```

and when i call

```
mutation {
  productCreate(input: {store:"61d6f33a58c4dc4e8a1a0536", title: "Sweet new product", vendor: "JadedPixel"}) 
  {
      _id 
  }
}
```

Result is

```
{
  "data": {
    "productCreate": {
      "_id": "61de591c58c4dcb08dffafa9"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to add additional paramenter to query and also get additional paramenter in result

So, my question is

What should i change in code

```
mutation {
  productCreate(input: {title: "Sweet new product", productType: "Snowboard", vendor: "JadedPixel"}) {
    product {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

to get result like this

```
{
  "productCreate": {
    "product": {
      "id": "1071559610"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions

Just need to change code like this

```
module Mutations
  class ProductCreate < BaseMutation

    field :product, Types::ProductType, null: true

    # TODO: define arguments
    argument :title, String, required: true
    argument :vendor, String, required: false
    argument :store, ID, required: true

    # TODO: define resolve method
    def resolve(title:, vendor:, store:)
      record  = Product.create!(title: title, vendor: vendor, store: store)

      { product: record }
    end
  end
end
```

source of an example
https://www.keypup.io/blog/graphql-the-rails-way-part-2-writing-standard-and-custom-mutations